# magento : different shipping cost for some products

Tags: shipping

We have a default shipping cost of 1,95 euro flat rate.

We'd like to have a 4,95 shipping cost for bulkier / heavier products.

We tried using a plugin for shipping cost per product.

This results on : if you have 2 products in the cart it calculates not 4,95 but 2x4,95=9,90

Is there a way to get (SOME) products to have 4,95 shipping default and the rest should keep the 1,95 shipping cost?

Comment: Which Magento version & platform?

Answer (score 8):

Magento has native support for this type of shipping, it is called 'Table Rates'.

Go to

> Admin > System > Configuration > Shipping Methods > Table Rate

Then select your website scope, from the drop down menu in the top left corner.

Then in the table-rates section, you'll see a button to export the CSV. Then edit it to suit your needs.

What you want to use is "Weight vs. Destination" - which will allow you to set a different shipping rate based on the `weight` attribute on your product. You can also specify a destination if you want, or use `*` for everything.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Magento configuration panel look for your shipment methods. It will download a `.csv` file with all the delivery types and prices.

There you can add a new method and make it visible just for that product.

Specify the price and a the weight range you want. Example: from 1kg to 100kg it will cost 4,95e.

Answer (score 1):

We also have developed an extension that simply allows you to specify a flat rate for per first individual product and also for per additional product.

You can use this extension for configuring flat rates for per first item and for per additional item of you magento store.

Here’s the link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/per-product-flat-shipping.html

Answer (score 1):

you could create an attribute or a category where you mark all your oversized products,

then install the extensio [Owebia-Shipping](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/owebia-shipping-2.html)

add a config file ([see the documentation](http://www.owebia.com/os2/en/doc)) using the above created attribute or category in the conditions.

Comment: I just discovered this extension and share it as it got me out of an issue where my cheap carrier has size limitations so I could not set it up with the standard Magento offer... basically, similar as your situation

Answer (score 1):

For this sole purpose we have created an extension called Product Shipping Rates per Country. Using the extension you can set up shipping rates per product per country. You can also chose to override the total shipping costs, or to add them up.

The extension can be configured to suit your needs exactly. The result would be as follows:

Example configuration:

- Shipping costs for product 1, no matter the amount ordered: 1.95
- Shipping costs for product 2, no matter the amount ordered: 4.95
- Shipping costs for product 2 and product 1 together, no matter the amount ordered: 4.95

There are many other possibilities to set up the shipping costs in Magento using this extension. A big plus is that you can configure the rates per product, and don't have to use the product weight for this.

Extension page:

https://plugin.company/magento-extensions/shipping-rates-per-product-per-country.html

Magento Connect:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-shipping-rates-per-country-by-plugin-company.html

If you're looking for weight based shipping costs calculation on the other hand, I'd recommend looking into Magento's built in "table rates" functionality. Using this system you can create shipping cost rules based on weight / destination.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I used a combination of two extensions:

1st
http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/set-shopping-cart-price-rule-conditions/

To define some rules for checkout (this plugin is also able to enable/disable payment options based on attributes).

2nd
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ig-multi-flat-shipping.html

To define multiple Flat-Rate shipping options.

Both extensions claim that they only work with version 1.6 and lower. I'm using 1.7 and had no problems so far.